# Null value in Django ORM model object's primary key

Tags: database, django, postgresql, orm, django-models

I have a Django ORM model that needs to integrate with a legacy database. The model was generated via `manage.py inspectdb`, and the class definition is like so:

```
class ClientJob(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column="id")
    CustomerGuid = models.CharField(max_length=40, db_column='CustomerGUID', blank=True)
    JobGuid = models.CharField(max_length=40, db_column='JobGUID', blank=True)
    AgentGuid = models.CharField(max_length=40, db_column='AgentGUID', blank=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = u'ClientJob'
```

The primary key `id` was originally defined as `models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)`, but from my understanding of Django this needs to be an AutoField if I want it to automatically increment hence the change.

I can query for objects without any issues, but when I run into trouble when I attempt to create and save a new object. The following code throws an `IntegrityError` with the message "null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint".

```
new_job = ClientJob.objects.create(CustomerGuid=customer_guid, JobGuid=str(uuid4()), AgentGuid=agent_guid)
new_job.save()
```

I suspect (but by no means certain) that this might be because my ClientJob table's primary key depends on a custom sequence. The definition of the sequence is as follows:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq_client_job_id
  INCREMENT 1
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
  START 11020
  CACHE 1;
ALTER TABLE seq_client_job_id
  OWNER TO ssa;
```

Any help shedding light on this will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply delete or uncomment the `id` line in your modelclass - it should work like a charm.

```
class ClientJob(models.Model):
    #id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column="id")
    CustomerGuid = models.CharField(max_length=40, db_column='CustomerGUID', blank=True)
    JobGuid = models.CharField(max_length=40, db_column='JobGUID', blank=True)
    #...
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I still get the same error. I've even recreated the database after making the change (i.e. not `manage.py syncdb`, actually dropped the database, re-created it, and reinstalled my Django app and then did a `manage.py syncdb`).

Comment: hrm... :( I'm sorry - I got no idea what else it could be.

Comment: This was the correct answer after all. It turns out that the other database I'm integrating with was't set up correctly, and the primary keys were of the INTEGER type instead of SERIAL. Once that was fixed, getting rid of the `id` in my Django model objects worked.

Comment: Yes, I confirmed this works. My models were created by inspectdb command and theirs meta class has 'managed: False'